# Select from RDBMS using Anorm and Play 2.2 for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I've put down this code in order to retrieve a row from a table using Anorm, but I got an error. Here's the code:

```
case class UserInquiry(
    id:Long, description:String
)

object UserInquiry {
   val byIdStmt = """
      SELECT id, description FROM user_inquiry WHERE id = {id}
   """

   def findById(id: Long) = {
      DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
         SQL(byIdStmt).on("id" -> id).apply().collect {  
            case Row(Some(id:Integer), Some(description:String)) => 
            new UserInquiry(id.toLong, description)
         }.head
      }    
   }
}

// This gives me an error
val id = UserInquiry.findById(7)
```

Here's the error:

```
[MatchError: Row('ColumnName(user_inquiry.id,Some(id))':4 as java.lang.Integer,
'ColumnName(user_inquiry.description,Some(description))':My search as java.lang.String)
(of class anorm.SqlRow)]
```

If I remove the 'id' column from the SQL statement and I remove its reference from the code in order to get only the column called 'description', everything works just fine.

What's wrong in the 'id' column? Why there's no match if it is a java.lang.Integer column? Is there maybe a class specific to DB 'Primary Keys'?

Comment: check if you are using the right database. You can also call head() first and then use map. I doubt it will make it work but you should do that instead of collect. I've never used Anorm but seems right to me to do that :p

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't make it work. About the DB, I'm connected to the only one I configured. INSERTS and UPDATES work as expected, though.

Comment: It seems id gets mapped to a String...

Comment: And where can you see that?? The error message says: 4 java.lang.Integer

Comment: @Max, Can you provide me the solution that how you are getting only column called: 'description' values for your question, as I have similar issue.

Comment: If you need only a column from your query just remove all other columns from the SELECT clause of your SQL statement. Then modify the pattern matching section "case Row(Some(column: String)) => new YourObject(description)". Notice you have to wrap your column into "Some()" in if you declared it nullable.

Comment: @Max, I am trying for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619921/runtimeexception-class-org-postgresql-util-pgobject-to-string-for-column-column, but I am not getting any solution for it, Please let me know how can I do it ?

Comment: @Max, I am able to get my json response, but it is showing with some extra styling like: Stream, slashes(\) and ?. I am not sure how can I remove those from my json ? Can you please help me at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619921/how-to-show-proper-json-response-from-scala-controller-class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got what was wrong:

being the 'id' column a PK, the following line of code

```
case Row(Some(id:Integer), Some(description:String))
```

has to be changed into:

```
case Row(id:Integer, Some(description:String))
```

That's because a PK column cannot be NULL, then it is not expected to use an Option[T] object for encapsulate the value retrieved from the DB.