# How to show proper json response from Scala controller class?

Tags: json, postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

I am trying to get json response from Postgresql database(v9.5) table to display on my view page, I have tried the following, as my application is executing fine, but I am not getting/displaying my required proper json data(as it is containing: Stream, slashes() and question mark(?), like Stream type json). Please let me know that how to show my desired output like below ?
my output:

```
Stream("[{\"_testid\":{\"testid0\":\"testnumber\"},\"testtitle\":\"TestTitle\"}]", ?)
```

but my desired output:

```
[{"_testid":{"testid0":"testnumber"},"testtitle":"TestTitle"}]
```

contorller:

```
class Test extends Controller {
    def getTest = Action { 
    var sql: SqlQuery = SQL("select name::TEXT from test");
    def values: String =  DB.withConnection { implicit connection => 
    sql().map(row => row[String]("name")).toString
    }
    Ok(values)
    }
```

table:

```
create table test(
    id serial primary key,
    name json not null);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Scala controller class to return JSON response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597942/how-to-write-scala-controller-class-to-return-json-response)

Comment: it would be nice you keep discussing on the same question, instead of creating 4 question per day on the same issue. I also suggest you have a look at the documentation before.

Comment: @cchantep, yeah, sure I will try to maintain only one query post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation, Anorm comes with [column parsers](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm#Column-parsers) for the JDBC standart types.

PostgreSQL JSON type is not one of those. It's a vendor specific type.

You can deal with this specific conversion in the statement, by casting the SQL column to `TEXT` before to go through the JDBC (as plain JDBC String so).

```
SELECT json_col::TEXT FROM test
```

You can implement a custom `Column[JsValue]` (see documentation), that convert the `PGObject` specific to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver into a Play `JsValue`.

You can map the column as `anorm.Object` (`SqlParser.get[anorm.Object]("col")`), and deal with the opaque value in your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am using Play 2.2.x, as I cannot see any documentation for column parsers on anorm, and Can I know how can I apply the above solution on my query as I am learning these now a days ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The conversion (`::text`) is best option with such obselete version.

Comment: If I write: val selectJson = SQL("select id,name::text from test"), I am getting error: [JsonMappingException: This ResultSet is closed.] at line Ok(response)

Comment: Check your connection, your driver, use your debugger, and/or update to a stable release.

Comment: I am getting my json data now but it is not coming as per my requirement(as it is having some slashes(\) and Stream and question mark(?), I am not sure why it is displaying like that ? Can I know about it please ? I have updated the question and description.